# Heroku Connect - No connections found

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-connect

I am trying to use heroku connect with my salesforce instance.
I have added Heroku connect as addon together with my postgresql.

[image]

This is what I am getting when I am clicking on it:

[image]

Am I missing some misconfiguration? What can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a conflicting behaviour between two heroku users connecting.
on the cli I have one user meanwhile in the browser there was another user connected